# PHP web push with no library

Tags: php, rest, web-services

Is there an easy way to send out push notifications in PHP without using external libraries? Here is my current code. when executed the server gives a **400 UnauthorizedRegistration** error. I do not care about how fast or efficient the process is, I am fine with sending one notification at a time.
My PHP code is:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","1");
$endpoint = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/fImmyvrGiSo:APA91bFg8A4N4GLmJMhouxPfw_R3ocv44uBaNkZu_JMVjAvueISJUJTQROpVxlBnX8PIeJGwE5s1pvLAldtcW-z6WzZ0Ixus2fc3jUADGbJ2L8kAdMv56S5cSmKMsFmPwDsdd2MoCrHC";

$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        "p256dh" => "BAHBGTIPl7M1v8Ui7EaNVlauLmi_jEJOreCQ3YTRu_nWgF4k8nwP5rewGWO86-3wP8yZ86GoKjHQpK_0sls05FI=",
        "auth" => "V08681gA2Gs_2x_UNFCN0g=="
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'ignore_errors' => true,
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

// here file_get_contents is used to send a POST request
$result = file_get_contents($endpoint, false, $context);
echo $result;
?>
```

My push subscription is:

```
{"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dcgCC59wHCE:APA91bHEzFoal6MXgXWt16aSdGHFAeS7D4vre99pCvzU_QWK22YFkmYdUQ5OmiLmUUbuhyiFEDHg61TrpllZ-TcaSgqXXOIcyTUf_0I-ngZ--aH2OFnEIrB2eI-ZRiArHD5LVAAz1EiM","expirationTime":null,"keys":{"p256dh":"BAHBGTIPl7M1v8Ui7EaNVlauLmi_jEJOreCQ3YTRu_nWgF4k8nwP5rewGWO86-3wP8yZ86GoKjHQpK_0sls05FI=","auth":"V08681gA2Gs_2x_UNFCN0g=="}}
```

Comment: It's presumably possible, but `400 UnauthorizedRegistration` presumably means you're not sending the right authorization credentials, incorrectly calculating a signature, or something else similar. **Why wouldn't you use the official SDK for this, though?** It handles all this stuff!

Comment: how about using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)?

Comment: @ceejayoz I know its a bit late but do you have a link to the offical SDK? I've been struggling to implement notifications myself...